# Android background music game pauses before looping

Tags: android, media-player

I'm working on Android game, and I'm using standard Android components for it.

I have media player object that should play background music over and over again.
I've composed some music, and rendered it...and it loops perfectly.

Now when I've added my music file into game...before every loop music stops for a moment...but it is very annoying. Why is that happening?

I've tested it on 2.3.3 phone device and ICS emulator...and the same thing happens every time.

This is my code:

```
/** Play background music */
public static void playMusic() {

    if (backgroundMusic == null) {
        backgroundMusic = new MediaPlayer();
        backgroundMusic.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);

        try {
            backgroundMusic.setDataSource(activity.getAssets()
                    .openFd("background_music.ogg")
                    .getFileDescriptor());
            backgroundMusic.prepare();
            backgroundMusic.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            backgroundMusic.setLooping(true);
            backgroundMusic.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

When I play the same file in some player on PC it loops and sounds very nice...
How to fix this? Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Well, unfortunately, it just works like that.
The problem is that he restarts the player, **after** it finished.

If you are using API 16 or greater, you can use the [setNextMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setNextMediaPlayer%28android.media.MediaPlayer%29)-method. He then tries to start the next `MediaPlayer` in a way, that there is no pause.

If you are developing for API smaller than 16, I don't know how you can handle this with a `MediaPlayer`.

You might try to work with 2 `MediaPlayers` and start the second one right before the first one stops. But I don't know how good that works, since you somehow have to find out, when exactly to start the new player.

**Edit:**
After some more google work, I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/98QAKhZRTLA).
Someone suggested to convert the `mp3`-File to an `ogg`-File, what would make it possible to loop it without having a pause. But I didn't try that.
According to comments, this worked for one person, but not for another one.

Comment: Sorry for giving you bad news :/

Comment: Yes, I saw that it was ogg. Unfortunately, I don't have an solution for this.

Comment: Ok, is there a way some other way to make my music loops correctly?

Comment: You might have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309931/android-dev-3rd-party-media-player-sdks-or-other-options). Maybe the thirdparty players are doing better than the `MediaPlayer`. I've got a MP3-Player with the same issue when using `MediaPlayer` :(  But I didn't test anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found a way to make this work...

I've changed code to this:

```
/** Play background music */
public static void playMusic() {

    if (backgroundMusic == null) {
        backgroundMusic = new MediaPlayer();
        backgroundMusic.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);
        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        try {
            afd = activity.getAssets().openFd(
                    "background_music.ogg");
            backgroundMusic.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                    afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            backgroundMusic.setLooping(true);
            backgroundMusic.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        backgroundMusic.start();
    }

}
```

Now it loops fine...the problem is that I don't really understand why...

Hope this will be helpful for some folks that had the same problem as me.

Cheers!